# UILabel word wrapping + multiline

Tags: ios, text, uilabel, word-wrap

What is the way to make UILabel to wrap text by words properly while number of lines is dynamic ( == 0 )? I tried so far different options and non of them resolve my problem..

I expect to have this:

```
RANDOMIZE
4
```

Plain text with number of lines = 0:

[image]

Even fixed number of lines doesn't work:

[image]

Attributed with Hyphenation = 1:

[image]

Comment: its simple don't fit in your label width size, and minimum font scale don't work if you use 0 as number of line, I think you should use 2 as number of lines instead

Comment: @ReinierMelian I have to have dynamic number of lines due to text in this label is dynamic. And what do you mean by "don't fit in your label width size" ?

Comment: I mean the screen size width for your Label font size

Comment: @ReinierMelian ok I see. But second screenshot shows that this also doesn't work: numberOfLines = 2... It doesn't try to reduce the font size in order to fit the text

Comment: I don't think you'll be successful with this approach. In order for Autoshrink to do its job, your label needs a height constraint. If you set Lines to `0`, Line Break to `Truncate Tail`, add a Height constraint of, say, `140`... and then add an actual newline between `RANDOMIZE` and `4` (press Option+Return when editing the label's text), you should see something close to what you're going for. More likely, though, you'll need to do it in code. Take a look here: http://www.11pixel.com/blog/28/resize-multi-line-text-to-fit-uilabel-on-iphone/

Answer (score -1):

you can set top ,bottom, trailing and leading constraints of ui label and set number of lines 0.
Hope it works for you.